# How can I prevent refinished tub from chipping?

Tags: bathtub, refinishing

I've used the Rust-Oleum 7860519 Tub And Tile Refinishing 2-Part Kit twice over the last 4 or 5 years for a rental property I own and each time a renter leaves, the finish as chipped off in several spots. It's usually worse around the drain.

Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Comment: How well does the product work in your own home? I'm trying to grasp if it's a shoddy product or if the tenants are abusing it.

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't/don't use it in my own home as I don't have a need for it. I doubt that the tenants are abusing it. I'm guessing that it occurs from bottles being dropped or even just the constant pounding of water.

Comment: 1) What is the composition of the tub?  2) How did you prepare the surface?  3) What application procedure are you suing around the drain (e.g., removing the drain before painting)?  4) What is the condition of the surface in the area of the chips (e.g., painting over previous chip or corrosion vs. good surface, just random impact location)?